# Cannot get tag's text even if setting a NamespaceContext

Tags: java, xpath, xml-namespaces

I am new to xpath , and I have never dealt with xml on java. I want to get values from a xml. The tags may be preceded by `mgns1:` or not. So I wrote this code :

```
private List<String> parse(Node node, String file) throws XPathExpressionException {

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {

        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            return prefix.equals("mgns1") ? "urn:edeveloper.Fournisseurs1031af" : null;
        }

        public Iterator<?> getPrefixes(String val) {
            return null;
        }

        public String getPrefix(String uri) {
            return null;
        }
    });

    Node node_codreg = (Node) xpath.evaluate("mgns1:CODREG", node, XPathConstants.NODE);

    ...

}
```

I tried with a xml which does not have the `mgns1:`. But at runtime I get no ListNodes ! So what is wrong ?

**edit :**

here is an example of an xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Fournisseurs>

  <JournalExtract>2</JournalExtract>

  <Record>
    <STATUTRECORD>S</STATUTRECORD>
    <CODFOUR>148</CODFOUR>
    <RAISOC></RAISOC>
    <ADRFOUR></ADRFOUR>
    <CPVILLE></CPVILLE>
    <CODPAYS></CODPAYS>
    <TELEPHONE></TELEPHONE>
    <TELEX></TELEX>
    <FAX></FAX>
    <EMAIL></EMAIL>
    <SIRET></SIRET>
    <CONDPAIE></CONDPAIE>
    <MODPAIE></MODPAIE>
    <LIVR></LIVR>
    <REMISE>0.00</REMISE>
    <DEVISE></DEVISE>
    <CLASSE></CLASSE>
    <DELMOY>0.00</DELMOY>
    <TVAIC></TVAIC>
    <MOTCLE></MOTCLE>
    <DTEAGR>00/00/0000</DTEAGR>
    <CODREG></CODREG>
    <MTMINFAC>0.00</MTMINFAC>
    <MTMINFRANCO>0.00</MTMINFRANCO>
    <ZL01></ZL01>
    <ZL02></ZL02>
    <INDQUAL></INDQUAL>
    <CERTIF></CERTIF>
    <DTEVALMIN>00/00/0000</DTEVALMIN>
    <DTEVALMAX>00/00/0000</DTEVALMAX>
    <RAISOCREGL></RAISOCREGL>
    <ADRREGL></ADRREGL>
    <CPVILLEREGL></CPVILLEREGL>
    <PAYSREGL></PAYSREGL>
    <DOMBQE></DOMBQE>
    <CODEBQE></CODEBQE>
    <CODGUI></CODGUI>
    <COMPTE></COMPTE>
    <RIB></RIB>
    <TYPETVA></TYPETVA>
    <IBANPAYS></IBANPAYS>
    <IBANCLE>00</IBANCLE>
    <IBANCOMPTE></IBANCOMPTE>
    <CODEBIC></CODEBIC>
    <ROUTAGECDE></ROUTAGECDE>
    <ACHSYSFRTVA>false</ACHSYSFRTVA>
    <URL></URL>
    <REMINCPXNET>false</REMINCPXNET>
    <NOTMANSYST>false</NOTMANSYST>
    <PROSPECT>false</PROSPECT>
    <FOUPREF>false</FOUPREF>
    <FOUPPAL></FOUPPAL>
    <DTEMODTRI>00/00/0000</DTEMODTRI>
    <NUMDUNS></NUMDUNS>
    <CODLGFOU></CODLGFOU>
    <NOALIMAUTSF>false</NOALIMAUTSF>
    <AUTCDECH>false</AUTCDECH>
    <SEUILEPDIF>false</SEUILEPDIF>
    <MTMAXCDECH>0.00</MTMAXCDECH>
    <MTMAXCC>0.00</MTMAXCC>
    <MTMAXCCHCT>0.00</MTMAXCCHCT>
    <CP></CP>
    <VILLE></VILLE>
    <CPREGL></CPREGL>
    <VILREGL></VILREGL>
    <CAMINST>0.00</CAMINST>
    <CAMAXST>0.00</CAMAXST>
    <OCCASION>false</OCCASION>
    <ID_EXT></ID_EXT>
    <TAXE2></TAXE2>
    <TAXE3></TAXE3>
    <TAXE4></TAXE4>
    <DTECREDEM>00/00/0000</DTECREDEM>
    <BDC_ELEC>false</BDC_ELEC>
    <TYPE_FORM></TYPE_FORM>
    <FORMAT>0</FORMAT>
    <MODE_ENV></MODE_ENV>
    <MAIL_DEST></MAIL_DEST>
    <ADR_FTP></ADR_FTP>
    <USR_FTP></USR_FTP>
    <PWD_FTP></PWD_FTP>
    <PATH_DEP></PATH_DEP>
    <RECEPT_AUTO>false</RECEPT_AUTO>
    <PERIODICITE></PERIODICITE>
    <NOCCGEN>false</NOCCGEN>
  </Record>

</Fournisseurs>
```

Comment: You'll need to supply an example of the XML you are querying. It's quite possible nodes are in a namespace even if they don't have a prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for elements named `mgns1:CODREG`, where mgns1 represents the namespace `urn:edeveloper.Fournisseurs1031af`.

In the XML document you have shown us, there are no elements in namespace `urn:edeveloper.Fournisseurs1031af`. So why would you expect your expression to select anything?

Moreover, you're only looking for direct children of the supplied `node` and you haven't told us what this node is. Perhaps you want to be looking for all descendants, not just direct children?